# Visual Studio auto-format ignoring user preferences

Tags: visual-studio, formatting

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017. I have the following preferences set regarding formatting:

[image: All "open brace on new line" checkboxes are ticked]

However, when I use the `Format Document` command (`CTRL + K`, `CTRL + D`), all open braces are formatted to be on the same line, like so:

```
public void A() {
}
```

Is this a bug with Visual Studio's automatic formatting, or is there another setting somewhere that needs to be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution that I had opened (from another source) had some pre-existing config files. I attempted to reproduce this problem in a fresh solution and everything appeared to work correctly.

The existing solution had a `rebracer.xml` file which appeared to be overriding the visual studio formatting settings (without updating the the preferences UI!).